# JFileChooser events

Tags: java, swing, events, jfilechooser

I have a button called "search" that opens a `JFileChooser` window. After double click of a directory that window should close automatically, so without clicking cancel or any other button. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by adding a [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) to the `JFileChooser`. Inside the [`propertyChange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html#propertyChange-java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent-) method check if the property name is [`JFileChooser.DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY). If it is, just call the [`JFileChooser.approveSelection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#approveSelection--) method which will close the file chooser dialog.

Note: Since selecting a folder will automatically close the file chooser, in this case it is important to direct the file chooser (the user) right to the folder where he/she can select the intended folder. For this purpose use the constructor of `JFileChooser` to set the initial/current folder (you can pass the folder either as a `File` or `String`), or you can set it after the constructor by calling [`JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory-java.io.File-).

Here is a complete example:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JButton b = new JButton("test");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        fc.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (JFileChooser.DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(
                        evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    System.out.println("DIRECTORY CHANGED");
                    fc.approveSelection();
                }
            }
        });

        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(f);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Chosen folder: " + fc.getSelectedFile());
        }
    }
});
f.add(b);

f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```